# How to make a private module pip installable?

Tags: python, pip

I have python package which need to be installed to run a Django project?

I go into the python virtual environment and clone the module from git in site-packages folder inside lib.

What i need is to make that module pip intallable and installation access should be given only to specific people i.e that module should not be public to everyone.

Comment: Don't clone into the site-packages. Just clone it to a temporary location. Then make sure you have the virtual environment activated and do `pip install <folder-name>` where the `<folder-name>` is the directory git created when you cloned. That should install the module to your virtual environment only.

Comment: can you tell me a way using Pypi?

Comment: Anything you upload to PyPi will be public. See @daniellong's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your package part of the requirements, place it where it will be accessible only by the people you want to have access, e.g. on a private github. Then you can add a line like this to any project's `requirements.txt`, and pip will fetch it and install it:

```
-e git://github.com/<user>/<package>.git#egg=<package>
```

(Replace  with the name of the package you are distributing.) This line is simply added to the list of simple package names that `requirements.txt` usually contains. You could also replace the git download with an egg placed on a local fileshare, or whatever.

Answer (score 7):

Build the python package as you normally would for a public build. For helpful step-by-step instructions on that front, check out the python [docs](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html)

There are a number of ways to maintain both installability and privacy. When I looked into this for my own packages I started with the suggestions at [this site](https://blog.chezo.uno/simple-way-to-distribute-your-private-python-packages-within-your-organization-fb7af5dbd4c9). This site includes instructions on how to build your own equivalent of a PyPi server.

The solution I landed on though, I feel is quite simpler. I pushed the entire package to a private git repository hosted on github. You can then install using `pip install git+[insert full url to your github repository here]`. You can enforce privacy by restricting who has access to your git repository.